# APOC installation neo4j desktop

Tags: neo4j, installation, neo4j-apoc

I run the neo4j desktop and I have to use the apoc procedure.

I have already installed the plugin apoc, and whitelisted in the .config file, but it keeps returning me this message:

```
There is no procedure with the name `apoc.help` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.
```

In the plugins folder i installed this version apoc-3.5.0.6. Have you got any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you manually installed the APOC plugin. You need to restart the neo4j server after you install a plugin.

Since you are using the Desktop, it is much easier to just tell the Desktop (in the right pane of the Project) to install the APOC plugin for you. That would ensure that the appropriate version of the APOC plugin is installed in the right place, and it will also restart the server for you.

Comment: I have done it using the desktop menu, but also checked it. I have restarted neo4j, may I should restart my pc ?

Comment: Should not be necessary to reboot the PC. Version 3.5.0.1 is pretty old. You could try installing a more recent version of neo4j and also the APOC plugin for it.