# apoc installed on neo4j desktop but no apoc procedures registered for database

Tags: neo4j, configuration, configuration-files, neo4j-apoc, neo4j-desktop

I cannot get APOC to work on neo4j.
Documentation is good ... when present!

I installed the apoc library via Neo4j Desktop:

1. Launch Neo4j Desktop
2. Locate DBMS
3. Select Plugins tab on right
4. installed the plugin

[image]

Then I open a project.

I try:

```
CALL apoc.load.json("file:///person.json")
YIELD value
RETURN value;
```

but

```
There is no procedure with the name `apoc.load.json` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.
```

Indeed The available procedures does not display `apoc`, in spite it is installed.

Then, after I cleared out that Neo4j Desktop is not using the installed community edition I had, and found that i can find the installed versions under the "more" options >  Terminal:

[image]

I checked that my neoj4.conf file have these lines:

```
# Leaving this unconfigured will load all procedures found.
#dbms.security.procedures.allowlist=apoc.coll.*,apoc.load.*,gds.*
```

(commented out, to load everything, so apoc should load...)

I think I have done OK, as here:
[APOC installation neo4j desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59653118/apoc-installation-neo4j-desktop)

I also tried to delete the project and set it up again:
https://community.neo4j.com/t5/general-discussions/some-apoc-procedures-not-available/m-p/41590

but still not working...

--

- How do I get APOC to work ??
- Do I have to install it for each project ?
- Do I need to configure it for each DB in the project ?

I am using neo4j desktop 1.5.6.

---

#Edited
today I replicated steps of yesterday, paying attention to the recommendations of @William Lion answer.

At launch of neo4j Desktop, I was prompted an alert that "Local graph password has been changed".

That is strange, because I have not changed it...

It did not accept nor my previous password (the one I use for the server), nor the default 'neo4j', but could pass the alert because I could `ignore this change until the next Graph start`.

So I ignored it, and was prompted to enter the password to connect with the neo4j server. And this time, apoc were found.

I tried to close the neo4j desktop, quitting from all open projects, and relaunch. This time I was not asked to input the password for the local dbms. So, I assumed the to have restarted the `next Graph`, following the previous alert, and I was expected to be requested to input the password again.

Maybe the problem was here. So, to avoid future hiccups:

- does neo4j reset the password of local dbms itself after a while or after certain conditions ?
- after neo4j desktop closes, am I sure all server and open dmbs instances are properly shut down ? What does `until the next Graph start` actually mean ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Plugins must be installed for each DBMS instance in Neo4j Desktop (there can be multiple DBMS instances in each project). Also, there can only be one active DBMS in Neo4j Desktop at a given time. Make sure that you have installed the plugin for the DBMS instance that you want to work with AND that DBMS is the one that is currently running. I'm guessing that you successfully installed the plugin for one DBMS, but tried querying with a different active DBMS that did not have the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with the LocalDBMS with version 5.12. After Installing APOC from the plugin, still it didn't work.

When I tried within a new project with LocalDBMS of version 4.4.29 it worked.

Might be worth exploring different versions.

Comment: Downgrading from 5.12 worked for me also, thanks!